# Can't install Haskell QuickCheck

Tags: haskell

I need to install Haskell's QuickCheck.  I try to run `cabal install QuickCheck`, and receive the following messages:

```
Resolving dependencies...
In order, the following would be installed:
primitive-0.6 (new package)
template-haskell-2.9.0.0 (latest: 2.10.0.0) (reinstall) changes:
containers-0.5.5.1 -> 0.5.6.3
tf-random-0.5 (new package)
QuickCheck-2.8.1 -base4point8 (new package)

cabal: The following packages are likely to be broken by the reinstalls:
ghc-7.8.3
Use --force-reinstalls if you want to install anyway.
```

I am quite new to Haskell, but I have a sneaking suspicion that breaking ghc is not a viable solution.  Any advice?  Thanks!

PS.  ghc and cabal-install were installed using MacPorts.  The ghc version is, as indicated above, 7.8.3.  The port version of cabal-install is hs-cabal-install @1.18.0.5_1.  Additionally, I've encountered this error on two different machines; one is running OS 10.9, the other 10.10.

Comment: Use sandboxes to separate your different package databases and not mess up your main environment: https://www.haskell.org/cabal/users-guide/installing-packages.html#developing-with-sandboxes

Comment: Try installing with the flags `--constraint='template-haskell installed' --constraint='containers installed'`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a per-user `cabal` installation and not a [sandbox](http://chromaticleaves.com/posts/cabal-sandbox-workflow.html), running `cabal install --reinstall --force-reinstalls QuickCheck` is fine. Using sandboxes is still much better though.

Comment: The non-sandbox solution appears to have worked, despite the warnings about possibly breaking ghc.  Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I am also new to Haskell but it seems that people should use `stack` nowadays.

If so,

`$ git clone https://github.com/stackbuilders/quickcheck-manual
 $ cd quickcheck-manual/
 $ stack setup
 $ stack install`

Ref/See https://github.com/stackbuilders/quickcheck-manual